# How to obtain values within an ng-repeat div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a modal with with a div that consists of: 
1. One text input.
2. Two drop downs.

I also have buttons that Add and Remove the above mentioned div as need be, and I am achieving the same in the following way :

```
$scope.data = [{}];
```

1.Adding:

```
        $scope.addRow = function(){
           $scope.data.push({});            
        }
    }
```

2. Removing:

   ```
       $scope.removeRow = function(){
       $scope.data.splice($scope.data.length-1,1); 
   }
   ```

This works well, it adds and removes the div appropriately.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="count in data">
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" ng-model="inputNumber" class="form-control" ng-required="true" autofocus="true"/>
        </div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="controls">
          <select class="form-control" ng-options="item.Data for item in items" ng-model="init"></select> 
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="controls">
          <select class="form-control" ng-options="item for item in allItems" ng-model="getNewData"></select> 
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

It basically consists of the text input field and two dropdowns with certain options.

My question here is, as and when I 'add' or 'remove' this div with the values that I input - How can I get all of the inputted values in my controller function and store it in an array?

A console.log on angular.toJson($scope.data) gives me an empty output.

What am I missing, and how can I get the values of all the rows for each of my fields?

Comment: You are trying to access all objects in data array?

Comment: Yes - which basically holds the entire div - including the text field and drop down values.

Comment: You are repeating in data array and holding each value in count object. But you never use it in your row div.

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be coming from all over the map. So it's hard to tell what is going on here. Your outer ng-repeat is repeating over count in data, but you never refer to that again. Your text input isn't even bound to an ng-model at all, so I'm not sure what the point of requiring it is.

What I'd suggest is create an array of objects that have properties that drive your two selects and one input. So maybe like this:

```
//these names are coming from your code. I know they make no sense, but there's not enough in your code to figure out what the sensible names would be

$scope.data = [
   {id:1, inputVal:'', init:'', getNewData:''},
   {id:2, inputVal:'', init:'', getNewData:''}
]
```

In this case, you'll probably want to add a "track by" since these are empty objects. I assume your real objects have real values they can use, but I don't have the information to put anything in there.

Then you can set your ng-model on the text input to `count.inputVal`, the first select to `count.init`, and the second select to `count.getNewData`. Your delete button would point to the entire selected item from your $scope.data collection, so all its properties would be right there.

Comment: Thanks for this! The issue is that - the ng-models linked to my inputs are calling different functions that basically loads the drop down values - is there a way I could access the input values within the ng-repeat ? The count is basically holding each of the divs - so something that goes within the div , to the input fields ?

Comment: The select options and the ng-model are/should be unrelated. The ng-model is the thing the user selected, not the list of things the user can select from.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment above. This maybe your solution;

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="count in data">

         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-required="true" autofocus="true" ng-model="textInput"/>
        </div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="controls">
          <select class="form-control" ng-options="item.Data for item in count.data" ng-model="init"></select> 
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="controls">
          <select class="form-control" ng-options="item for item in count" ng-model="getNewData"></select> 
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

You can access "textInput" via "$scope.textInput" in your controller. Also you can see all the objects in your "item.Data" by repeating in "count.data" or  which ever the field name in your object. But be sure that data field in count object is an Array. In your 3rd div, you access it with "$scope.getNewData" in your controller. But you must be repeating in count object and count object should be an Array.I hope it works.